# Select correct environment.ts in webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

Inside my webpack.config.js, I am returning the correct webpack config file based on passed env:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    return require(`./webpack.${env}.js`)
};
```

Inside my webpack.prod.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [{test: /.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader'}]
    },
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
       extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
    }
};
```

Then I have inside /src/environments, two environment files:

```
environment.ts
environment.prod.ts
```

In any of my other services, I refer to environment as:

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
```

Actually I got this idea from angular-cli.  And I would like to also use this in node.js.  My question is how do I specify in the webpack to rename environment.prod.ts and use that when building for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I did and it works as I expected.  First I install `file-replace-loader`, then I modified the webpack as follows:

```
const {resolve} = require('path');
...
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /.tsx?$/, 
        use: 'ts-loader'
    },{
        test: /environment\.ts?$/,
            loader: 'file-replace-loader',
            options: {
                condition: true,
                replacement: resolve('./src/environments/environment.prod.ts'),
                async: true
            }
       }
    ]
    ...
```

I set the condition to `true` since I am modifying the `webpack.prod.js`.

Answer (score 3):

In node environment specific context is toggled with variable [NODE_ENV](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html)